# 'Passing 'score' not found on object of type 'SKScene'' when passing integer from one scene to another

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

What I'm wanting to do is pass an integer finalScore from myScene to gameOverScene, so the user can see their final score on the game over scene.

Relevant code in myScene.m

```
-(void)gameOver
{
    SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:NO];
    gameOverScene.score = finalScore;
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:reveal];
}
```

Relevant code in gameOverScene.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int score;
```

However, on the following line, I am getting the error ''Passing 'score' not found on object of type 'SKScene''

```
gameOverScene.score = finalScore;
```

How do I fix this so that the integer created in myScene is available in gameOverScene? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the proper variable type. Change:

```
SKScene *gameOverScene = ...
```

to:

```
GameOverScene *gameOverScene = ...
```

Comment: thank you, that's worked! knew it would be something fairly simple.